# comparing properties values inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, object

so i'm doing some excercises as practice, since i'm a beginner, and i stumble into this problem that i can't solve, would anybody be kind to give me a hand?

i would like to make a function that returns how many people is 18 or older, this is what i've been trying but i'm a bit confused..

```
const examplePeople = [
  { name: 'John', age: 15 },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 16 },
  { name: 'Jack', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Ana', age: 18 },
  { name: 'Raul', age: 23 },
  { name: 'Pedro', age: 17 }
];

function countLegalPeople(people) {
  for (i= 0; i >= people["age"] ; i++){
    if (people[i]["age"] >= 18) {
      return people[i];
    }
  }
}

console.log(countLegalPeople(examplePeople));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't try [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const examplePeople = [
  { name: 'John', age: 15 },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 16 },
  { name: 'Jack', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Ana', age: 18 },
  { name: 'Raul', age: 23 },
  { name: 'Pedro', age: 17 }
];

function countLegalPeople(people) {
  return people.filter(p => p.age >= 18).length;
}

console.log(countLegalPeople(examplePeople));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `reduce`, where the accumulator is the number of objects found so far that pass the test:

```js
const examplePeople = [
  { name: 'John', age: 15 },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 16 },
  { name: 'Jack', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Ana', age: 18 },
  { name: 'Raul', age: 23 },
  { name: 'Pedro', age: 17 }
];

const result = examplePeople.reduce((a, { age }) => a + (age >= 18), 0);
console.log(result);
```

With a `for` loop, you'd have to increment a more persistent variable, eg

```js
const examplePeople = [
  { name: 'John', age: 15 },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 16 },
  { name: 'Jack', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Ana', age: 18 },
  { name: 'Raul', age: 23 },
  { name: 'Pedro', age: 17 }
];

let result = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < examplePeople.length; i++) {
  if (examplePeople[i].age >= 18) {
    result++;
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

But array methods are generally more terse and elegant IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your approach is that you are returning within your `for` loop. Whenever you return, your function will stop running (it essentially jumps out of your function), so, whenever you run into a person over the age of 18 you stop your loop and thus it cannot count any more people.

Instead, you can create a variable and set it to zero. This will count how many people of the age of `18` you have seen. To do this, you will need to add one to this variable each time you see a person of an age of 18 or higher. Then, once your for loop is complete, you can return this number.

See example below:

```js
const examplePeople = [
  { name: 'John', age: 15 },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 16 },
  { name: 'Jack', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Ana', age: 18 },
  { name: 'Raul', age: 23 },
  { name: 'Pedro', age: 17 }
];

function countLegalPeople(people) {
  let counter = 0; // number of people >= 18;
  for (let i= 0; i < people.length; i++){ // loop through the array of people (using people.length)
    if (people[i]["age"] >= 18) {
        counter++; // age 1 to counter (same as counter = counter + 1)
    }
  }
  return counter; // return the amount of people >= 18
}

console.log(countLegalPeople(examplePeople));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was slightly confusing and could be taken two different ways, so if you are looking to return the total instances of people that are 18 and older in a new array, you would do something like this:

```
const examplePeople = [
  { name: 'John', age: 15 },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 16 },
  { name: 'Jack', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Ana', age: 18 },
  { name: 'Raul', age: 23 },
  { name: 'Pedro', age: 17 }
];

let adults = [];
for (let i = 0; i < examplePeople.length; i++) {
  if (examplePeople[i].age >= 18) {
    adults.push(examplePeople[i]);
  }
}
console.log(adults);
```

you can also get the length with a simple:

```
console.log(adults.length);
```